# Saving pdf to BLOB (in mssql server) and output it back on website (php)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdf, blob

I need to save a pdf file into BLOB (database is MsSql 2012, but I would need it work on 2008 too).

Here is compilation of what I have tried so far:

(File `where I save pdf into database`)

```
function preparePDF2String($filepath)
{
    $handle = @fopen($filepath, 'rb');
    if ($handle)
    {
        $content = @fread($handle, filesize($filepath));
        $content = bin2hex($content);
        @fclose($handle);
        return "0x".$content;
    }
}

$out = preparePDF2String('pdf/pdf.pdf');
$q_blob = "INSERT INTO HISTORIA_ARCHIWUM_test(PDFName, PDFData) VALUES('First test pdf', $out) ";

$r_blob = mssql_query($q_blob,$polacz);
```

`Results` (ok, I think)

[image]

(Now the php file `where I try to output the pdf`)

```
// header('Content-type: application/pdf');
// readfile('pdf/pdf.pdf'); - this works just fine, so pdf is ok


$q_blob = "select top 1 * from HISTORIA_ARCHIWUM_test";
$r_blob = mssql_query($q_blob,$polacz);
$w_blob = mssql_fetch_array($r_blob);

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="the.pdf"');

echo $w_blob['PDFData'];
//echo hex2bin ($w_blob['PDFData']); - I also tried this - same problem
```

**Problem:** when I try to output the pdf in the browser I get error (this pdf is of not supported format). It won't open in Adobe reader also. My guess is that I output it wrong, but maybe it is the way I save it?

Comment: Why not save the PDF outside the database in filesystem, save its path link in database and have PHP use the link (much like images)? You avoid converting the binary content to string.

Comment: It's my client requirement. He need big pdf respository that is easy to copy (automatic backup - one big database file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT from comments**
 It seems php+mssql truncates string when you get it from db, but its manageable in php.ini. I set mssql.textlimit = 160000 and mssql.textsize = 160000 and it works fine with Hex conversion and varchar(max).

---

You are transforming the pdf data before you save it to the database, you have to undo the transformation before you output it.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="the.pdf"');

echo hex2bin(substr($w_blob['PDFData'], 2));
```

Also why are you transforming the data in the first place, just save it as binary.

Comment: Sorry for delayed answear (I had no access - yesterday was a non-working day here). I did try to undo transfromation, but with no sucess - I tried couple hex2binary functions (including those from php.net) and all see to have problem. Strange becouse in database it seems ok. You sugession not to do transformation is propably best way, but I have problem with that to. If I read pdf and try to save it in binary I get: Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: The identifier that starts with '.....' is too long. Maximum length is 128. So far I was not able to deal with this.

Comment: What type of field is PDFData? Try using VARBINARY(MAX)

Comment: It is VARBINARY(MAX) - and when to think about it this accually might be a problem if I do conversion to HEX :) (I assume that varbinary means binary only) - I need to figure out how to make my query work, without conversion. Really simple test: INSERT INTO HISTORIA_ARCHIWUM_test(PDFName, PDFData) VALUES('First test pdf', $out)  where out is read pdf.

Comment: Have you tried using a parameterized query to insert the data?

Comment: Good idea, I just need to learn how to do it becouse I never used them before :D - I will post results. In the meantime I found out that problem with this insert is propably lack of proper escape strings (for some reason php has problem with doing this well - I will investigate more).

Comment: Hmmm. Concerning parameterized query from what I see it requires sqlsrv extension. Unfortunatelly I'm limited to older mssql extension here (standard: mssql_query(query,conection)).

Comment: I might have figured out what is the problem. i just dont know how to handle it yet (I dont think I should ask it here, but maybe just ask another question?). Read pdf file (converted to HEX and stored in VARCHAR(max) not VARBINARY! ) has string lenght 88920, then i check what is stored in database, and it's 88920 too (select LEN(PDFData)). But what I read in php has only 4096 chars ($w_result['PDFData'] - the variable that comes from mssql_fetch_array) - I think this is where I lose data, in mssql_fetch_array function. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `select top 1 CONVERT(TEXT,PDFData) as PDFData  * from HISTORIA_ARCHIWUM_test`

Comment: No need. I just found solution. It seems php+mssql truncates string when you get it from db, but its manageable in php.ini. I set mssql.textlimit = 160000 and mssql.textsize = 160000 and it works fine with Hex conversion and varchar(max). Thank you for your help and your time. I appreciate that. Could you please add info from this comment to you answear too (so others find it more easy).