# Inserting a file in to the SQL database and retrieving it

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, file

My school’s web server does not allow us to upload files to it using `move_uploaded_file(….)`. Therefore, I am trying to learn how can I insert a PDF file in to a SQL server database filed and retrieve it later. I was able to put the  PDF file using the following code. But the retrieving file via the browser part does not work. It only prints the filed's values and does not save the file in to my computer. Any help would be appreciated

```
<?php
//Connection get established successfully
$connInfo = array(//code omitted);
$connect = sqlsrv_connect(//code omitted, $connInfo) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL), true));

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) //This part works
{
    // extract file name, type, size and path
    $file_path=$_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name']; //pdf is the name of the input type where we are uploading files
    $file_type=$_FILES['pdf']['type'];
    $file_size=$_FILES['pdf']['size'];
    $file_name=$_FILES['pdf']['name'];

    // checks whether selected file is a pdf file or not
    if ($file_name != "" && $file_type == 'application/pdf')
    {//PDF file may contains, images, tables, etc.. 
        $data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_path));

        //SQL Data type is varchar(MAX). query to update file in database.
        $query="UPDATE TestTable SET Data='".$data."' WHERE ID=1";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query); //query execution
        // Check if it was successful
        if($result)
            echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
        else
            echo '<br>Error!:'.sqlsrv_errors();
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'Not a pdf file. Try again';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['read'])) //Does not download the file!!
{
    //Query to fetch field where we are saving pdf file
    $sql = "SELECT Data FROM TestTable WHERE ID = '1'";
    $result2 = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql);    // query execution
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result2); // returns the current row of the resultset
    $pdf_content = $row->Data; // Put contents of pdf into variable
    $fileName = time().".pdf"; // create the unique name for pdf generated
    //download file from database and allows you to save in your system
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
    print $pdf_content;
}

?>

<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File: <input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf" accept="application/pdf" title="Choose File" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="read" id="read" value="Read" />
</form>
```

I am saving the full data value of the file in to the database filed(not inserting, updating an existing row). Not trying to save the file's path or text content of it alone. This save the PDF file in to the database filed in base64_encode. If I look at the content of the database after running this code, I see the row has been updated with something similar to the following: `JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjI0IDAgb2JqDTw8L0xpbmVhcml6ZWQgMS9MIDM1MTcyL08gMjYvRSAzMDI1Ni9OIDEvVCA .....`

Comment: Did you actually commit that `UPDATE` ? In other words, are you able to see the updated data in the database ?

Comment: I don't see an INSERT here, just an UPDATE.

Comment: It's also unclear if you're wanting to save the path to the file, or as a BLOB.

Comment: Seeing the edit: What is the column's type? This needs to be a BLOB. You can `@Funk` me or `@someone_else` here. We can't keep looking at the question here.

Comment: so, was I right here ^ ?? want an answer for it?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you for the comment. It's a Blob of data saved on that filed. varchar(MAX) is the data type.

Comment: Data type should be a BLOB, I feel.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner SQLsever doesn't have a data type called BLOB. Are there any other data type I should choose?

Comment: Right you are; use `varbinary` / `varbinary(MAX)` instead. My SQL-server skills aren't like MySQL.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I have done that. It looks like `varbinary(MAX)` doesn't like to take data in this format: `JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjI0IDAgb2....` Maybe I should convert the PDF file in to a different data type that matches the `varbinary`, other than base64_encode ?

Comment: *Hmm...*, I'd try and lose the `base64_encode()` and use a prepared statement, as in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18944368/1415724). and/or https://stackoverflow.com/q/33630714/1415724 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071537/save-pdf-as-a-blob-in-a-database-using-php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you for the additional information. I will try those out later and let you know. Since I am having to leave school now.

Comment: You're quite welcome. I hope something in there will be of use to you, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Next example demonstrates how to insert a PDF file into varbinary(max) column in SQL Server and then save this file to disk:

**T-SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VarbinaryTable] (
    [Data] varbinary(max) NULL
)
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
# Connection
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$uid = 'user';
$pwd = 'password';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => $database,
    "UID" => $uid,
    "PWD" => $pwd
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false)
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# Insert PDF file
$pdf = file_get_contents('PDFFile.pdf');
$sql = "INSERT INTO VarbinaryTable ([Data]) VALUES (?)";
# In your case:
# $sql = "UPDATE VarbinaryTable SET [Data] = ? WHERE ID = 1"; 
$params = array(
    array($pdf, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY), SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARBINARY('max'))
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error insert (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# Get PDF file and save it again on disk. 
$sql = "SELECT [Data] FROM VarbinaryTable";
# In your case:
# $sql = "SELECT [Data] FROM VarbinaryTable WHERE ID = 1"; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
if (sqlsrv_fetch($stmt)) {
    $pdf = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));
    file_put_contents('PDFFile-fromDB.pdf', $pdf);
}

# Output the file
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/pdf");    
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=PDFFile-fromDB.pdf");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("PDFFile-fromDB.pdf"));
readfile("PDFFile-fromDB.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me with an example. If I were to `echo` the result of `$pdf = file_get_contents('PDFFile.pdf');` I get some text similar to the following: `%PDF-1.6 %���� 24 0 obj <> endobj 31 0...`   But when I go to the data `Data` filed in the data base, that filed shows the following value: `<Binary data>` and nothing else in it. If I try to print the value of `$pdf = sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));` $pdf output the following result: `Resource id #12`. By the way, my intention is to save this retrieved data on a user’s windows desktop.

Comment: @DP. Updated answer. If you want to force a download, use `readfile()`.